# python PIL Pillow: save image suddenly does not work

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, python-imaging-library

I am using Pillow (PIL.Image) library in Anaconda Jupyter Notebook to open tif image, split it to several pages and save the image.
It was working last week.
However, suddenly it returns an OS error this week.

My code is as follow:

```
img = Image.open(file_url)
for i in range(img.n_frames): ## split multi-page tif
    print(i+1)
    try:
        img.seek(i)
        img.save('page_%s.tif'%(i,))
    except EOFError:
        break
```

And now I get this error:

```
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call
> last) <ipython-input-5-55bb7e23c7a6> in <module>
>       5     try:
>       6         img.seek(i)
> ----> 7         img.save('page_%s.tif'%(i,))
>       8     except EOFError:
>       9         break
> 
> ~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py in
> save(self, fp, format, **params)    2066     2067         # may mutate
> self!
> -> 2068         self._ensure_mutable()    2069     2070         save_all = params.pop("save_all", False)
> 
> ~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py in
> _ensure_mutable(self)
>     587     def _ensure_mutable(self):
>     588         if self.readonly:
> --> 589             self._copy()
>     590         else:
>     591             self.load()
> 
> ~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py in
> _copy(self)
>     580 
>     581     def _copy(self):
> --> 582         self.load()
>     583         self.im = self.im.copy()
>     584         self.pyaccess = None
> 
> ~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PIL\TiffImagePlugin.py
> in load(self)    1068     def load(self):    1069         if
> self.use_load_libtiff:
> -> 1070             return self._load_libtiff()    1071         return super().load()    1072 
> 
> ~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PIL\TiffImagePlugin.py
> in _load_libtiff(self)    1180     1181         if err < 0:
> -> 1182             raise OSError(err)    1183     1184         return Image.Image.load(self)
> 
> OSError: -2
```

I have checked that the Pillow library is the newest version.
Adding file type will make the cluster infinite busy but does not really store the image.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what happened to the library since last week, but I found the solution by reinstalling again...

Use "python -m pip install Pillow" instead of "pip install Pillow,"
and then restart the Jupyter Notebook as well as the laptop.

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same situation where the tiff to jpeg conversion was working initially but failed later with `OSError: -2` on `self._load_libtiff`.

After going through [this github post](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/4237#issuecomment-630871978), found out I needed to update libtiff 4.1.0 to build h885aae3_4 or later from conda-forge channel, so like:

`conda install -c conda-forge libtiff=4.1.0=h885aae3_4`